# Replace keys in PascalCase to maj SNAKE_CASE vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of i18n keys across **multiple files** that are in this format :

```
i18n.Exemple.MyExemple
```

I would like to replace all of the following with

```
I18N.EXEMPLE.MY_EXEMPLE
```

So basically, uppercase everything, and add a `_` before second MAJ.

I made a regex that looks like `(i18n\.)(.*?)(?=('|"))` which match all my i18n keys in the app.
but I can't find a way to convert all the match to uppercase in the **Global Search** in Vscode

But I am a bit lost on how to replace using the global search on vscode. I tried the `\u$1$2 but it replace with the same text. and do not even apply the uppercase

**EDIT :** Ok so the syntax is `\U$1\U$2` but I am missing the part where I add the `_` before my MAJ ? I guess I have to do in 2 steps. First replace

```
i18n.Exemple.MyExemple
```

to

```
i18n.exemple.my_exemple
```

and then

```
I18N.EXEMPLE.MY_EXEMPLE
```

I do not know how to do step 1 to 2

Comment: You could use extension `Text Manipulator` by Adam Walzer, select all the strings you want with find and then call the SnakeCase command

Comment: thanks for the comment, unfortunately, it looks like this extension require me to do file by files.

Comment: `(i18n\..*)([A-Z].*)` and replace with `\U$1_\U$2` Match case option `Aa` must be selected.

Comment: @Mark thanks it also look ok  !, but for Single word like `i18n.Action.Connection` this make it looks like `I18N.ACTION._CONNECTION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 to 2

Search Case Sensitive for

```
(?<=i18n\.[^'"]*[a-z])([A-Z])
```

replace with

```
_$1
```

**Edit**

In Global file search

```
(i18n\.[^'"]*?[a-z0-9])([A-Z])
```

replace with

```
$1_$2
```

Apply as often as needed

Comment: Thank you for the help, I got this error tho `lookbehind assertion is not fixed length` in vscode

Comment: @Bobby I just tested it with a name with 2 capitals and it worked, VSC found the 2 capitals and inserted `_` before, VSC 1.53

Comment: it does workish in the file regex matcher, not in the global search for all files

Comment: Thank you ! it does the job

Comment: @Bobby Enable the `Aa` button, the image is hard to view (very small)